# presentViewController makes black screen Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: xcode, view, screen

Hello you lovely reader,

I've been stuck on this for 2 days now so I really hope somebody could help me get this fixed. I get a blackscreen when switching views with Xcode 5.1.1. I saw this problem on stackoverflow but no post helped me.

I want to switch to view Connexion from view Inscription and be able to switch back to view Inscription from view Connexion. 
I do it with animation, here is the code from InscriptionViewController.m :

```
- (IBAction)swipeGestureToRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender { // Switch à la vue de connexion

    // get the view that's currently showing
    UIView *currentView = self.view;
    // get the the underlying UIWindow, or the view containing the current view
    UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];

    ConnexionViewController *vc = [[ConnexionViewController alloc] init];
    UIView *newView = vc.view;

    // remove the current view and replace with myView1
    [currentView removeFromSuperview];
    [theWindow addSubview:newView];

    // set up an animation for the transition between the views
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

    [[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchView"];

}
```

And here is the code from ConnexionViewController :

```
- (IBAction)swipeGestureToLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

What do you guys think ? Where can it come from ?

Thanks in advance for your time and help. 
:)

PS : I tried to remove all of this and replace by

```
ConnexionViewController *vc = [[ConnexionViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

And I still get a black screen.

EDIT : Problem Solved. Thx for your help. After 2 days I found out.

Here is the solution :

```
// get the view that's currently showing
UIView *currentView = self.view;
// get the the underlying UIWindow, or the view containing the current view
UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ConnexionViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ConnexionViewController"];

UIView *newView = vc.view;

// remove the current view and replace with myView1
[currentView removeFromSuperview];
[theWindow addSubview:newView];

// set up an animation for the transition between the views
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchView"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I faced same in xcode 5.1.1

Instead of presentViewController, I faced while pushViewController

Problem is xcode not able to automatically pick controller.xib file in my case, so I added xib name

Initially-

- self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

After-

- self = [super initWithNibName:@"UserConversationViewController" bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

It solves my problem, hope it will also solve someone's problem. :)